# Elimination theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Assumme $f_0, f_1 ... f_n$ is n+1 homogenous polynomials with fixed degree $d_0,d_1...d_n$ in variable $x_0...x_n$. So the number of polynomials is equal to the number of variables.

Then does there exists a polynomial D in coefficients of $f_i$'s s.t. D=$0$ iff $f_0=f_1=...=f_n=0$ has a nontrivial solution. For example, when all the $d_i$=1, the determinant of the corresponding matrix is the D.

But in general, how can I prove such polynomial D exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a polynomial exists and it's called the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

To prove that it exists, use the linked definition (the product of the differences of roots in an algebraic closure) and use the theory of symmetric polynomials (and/or a bit of Galois theory) to show that the coefficients lie in the base field.